# If A is a set of pairwise-disjoint sets, is the power set of A a set of pairwise-disjoint sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is just as in the title:
If A is a set of pairwise-disjoint sets, is the power set of A a set of pairwise-disjoint sets? Either prove this or provide a counterexample.

This is the question, and would like to double check my work on this problem; I provided a counterexample, but just want to be sure (or find out if that is wrong!).

Comment: Any $A$ with at least two elements will give you a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that answer is no. Consider $A = \{\{1\}\{0\}\}$. Then the sets $\{\{1\}\}, \{\{1\},\{0\}\}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$, and these sets are not disjoint.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I had a similar example where I used natural numbers in pairs as sets, A= {{2,3}, {3,4}}, where P(A) = [{{2,3}},{{3,4}}, {{2,3},{3,4}}, A], and that this is not pairwise disjoint. I hope this is the correct notation with the double parentheses and including A! Thanks again!